# Parsing rsync output

Tags: shell, tar, rsync

I am trying the parse the progress bar output of rsync command. I want to use the percentage data from the rsync progress bar and display it on a dialog gauge utility.

The rsync progress bar data looks like:

```
32768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
   330563584   8%  315.22MB/s    0:00:11
```

So far, I have tried sed to extract the data:

```
rsync -a --progress test.tar.gz /media/sdb1 \
    | sed -u -E 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\2/p'
```

I am able to obtain the final value 100 alone. I am not able to obtain the intermediate values.

Comment: Unless you would explicitly reject an answer using the bash read command, and not sed, why do you ask it this way?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am trying to use sed because I found [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44860/making-a-progressbar-with-dialog-from-rsync-output) during my search. This could be a solution if you are trying to transfer multiple files. I am trying to transfer a single large file. I thought sed or awk command is the way to go.

Comment: Does `rsync` actually output `\n` between progress lines, or just `\r`?  If the latter, `sed` is definitely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @ephemient Yes it uses CR and LF characters. I am currently trying to capture the data into a text file, read it line by line and use cut command to capture the percentage data. Is there a better way of doing this? Can I achieve this by piping the data?

Comment: So, first issue: `rsync --progress` shows a progress bar per-file, not a single one for the whole transaction. Are you sure this is what you want? If this is many small files, you'd be better off using the counters, not the percentages.

Comment: That is: A file will go straight to 100% if it's so small that it gets transferred in a single syscall; only very large files will ever display intermediate values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I solved the problem. I am doing the following: `rsync -a --progress test.tar.gz /media/sdb1 | unbuffer -p grep -o "[0-9]*%" | tr -d '%'` Now I am not able to pipe this to a dialog gauge box. But I am able to successfully print all numbers on stdout

Comment: @Sai Post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution to this problem. It could be done as follows:

```
    rsync -a --progress test.tar.gz /media/sdb1 |
    unbuffer -p grep -o "[0-9]*%" | 
    tr -d '%
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer [1] led me finally to the main issue, why nothing worked in the way I expected it.

With this the following sniplet gives you *all* output you can have for parsing. The "final" lines (e.g. the 100%, but also the xxx files to consider) but also the intermediate stuff only separated with ^M.

```
/usr/bin/rsync --info=progress2 --no-i-r -avr /foo /boar | \
 gawk '1;{fflush()}' RS='\r|\n' | \
while read -r i
do
 echo Got: -$i-
done
```

Note the remarks about the separation of line endings in the original answer.

[1] [Realtime removal of carriage return in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319179/realtime-removal-of-carriage-return-in-shell)